# Integrating with respect to arc length (ds) vs. dx, or dy

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

I'm learning line integrals. And I understand the concept of integration with respect to $ds$, but I don't know what $dx$ and $dy$ actually mean.

In my calc textbook, it just says that $dx$ is the same thing as $x^{'}(t)dt$ and likewise for *dy* being equal to $y^{'}(t)dt$.

But what do they mean physically. Intuitively I know that *ds* is the arc length, or a certain *curtain* in a sense. And I also know that if *ds* is present I just use the arc length formula, but for *dx* and *dy* I don't have to.

I looked at the other questions but I never understood that well.

Comment: why not start by specifying *exactly in which sense* is $ds$ a curtain.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero $ds$ is arc length. And $f(x,y)$ will represent $z$ values, which we multiply with $ds$ to get the area.

Comment: in what sense is this “a certain curtain”?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Dude, forget I said curtain. I just visualize it that way. If you know how to intuitively interpret $dx$ and $dy$ help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$dx$ is infinitesimal change in the $x$-direction. $dy$ is an infinitesimal change in the $y$-direction. $ds$ is an infinitesimal change in arc length. Think of them in a triangle. $dx$ and $dy$ are legs of the triangle, and $ds$ is the length of the hypotenuse.

You have to use the arc length formula for calculating arc length but not change in $x$ for the same reason that you need the Pythagorean theorem to compute the length of the hypotenuse of a triangle, but not the length of a leg.

It may be helpful to realize that while $ds$ depends on the particular shape of your curve, $dx$ and $dy$ always follow the coordinate axes. However in the case that your curve is a horizontal line, (or even just has $dy/dx=0$ for a point) then $ds=dx$. And if it is a vertical line (or even just has $dx/dy=0$ for a point), then $ds=dy.$

And in the case that $ds=dx$, then $\int f(x,y)\,ds=\int f(x,y)\,dx$ is just the standard integral of one variable from single variable calculus.

Comment: @Asker123 I guess we view the integral of a function along arc length of a curve as computing the area of a curvy sheet of varying height above the curve. A "curtain". Makes sense to me.

Comment: Yup, that's what I had in mind.

Comment: I got it but I have another question. Let's say $x = 0$ and $y = -t$. We can't say $ds$ = $dy$ because if you plug in $dy$ in the arc length formula you end up getting 1 for $ds$ but just taking the derivative of $y$ will give you -1. So why is it different?

Comment: @Asker123 yeah ok. so the usual integral $\int f(x,y)\,dy$ is a signed area, computed over an oriented interval. It cares about whether you traverse the interval from high to low, versus low to high, the latter has the opposite sign of the former. Arc-length and surface area and volume integrals are different integrals that are designed to not care about the orientation of the region of integration. Given an oriented integral $\int f(x,y)\,dy$, you can always turn it into an unoriented integral $\int f(x,y)\,|dy|$. So before when I said sometimes $ds=dy$, ...

Comment: it would have been more correct to say that $ds=|dy|$. As to the "why" of it all. Why do the 1d single variable integral, and the line integral, care about the orientation of the domain of integration, while arc length and surface area do not? why do we need these two kinds of integration? Well we certainly need the first kind of integral, because it is the orientations that make the fundamental theorem of calculus, and the divergence theorem, and Green's theorem, and Stokes' theorem work.

Comment: We also need the unoriented kind, because even nonorientable surfaces have a positive surface area. Because the norm of a vector is positive. Because lengths, areas, and volumes are positive. Measures are positive.  So to compute cumulative norms of changing vector fields, we just sum the norms, which is positive. Arc lengths, surface areas, and volume triple integrals should also be positive. So there are really two ways to integrate, one that cares about orientation and one that doesn't. That difference is what you're seeing here.